# Wilcoxon signed-rank test for just one sample: R vs. Python

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have tried to solve a simple college exercise about WSR test: first by hand, then in Python and finally in R. But I'm having an issue with the statistic I get.

I have a small sample of 21 numbers: 4, 5, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 8, 9, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 6. Null hypothesis, median equals 5; alternative, it doesn't. Alpha is 0.05 and not null differences (between sample elements and hypothetical median) are 17.

By hand, I get 68 for W- and 85 for W+. According to my notes, I have to choose the minimum of both, so 68, and it might be bigger than the critical value from the table, W17,0.05, which it seems to be 41. Great, I can't reject the null hypothesis.

In Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import wilcoxon as wil

sample = [4, 5, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 8, 9, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 6]
sample = np.array(sample)
med0 = 5

W, p = wil(sample - med0, correction = False, mode = 'approx')

print("W = %.1f, p-value = %.3f" % (W, p))
```

And I get:

```
W = 68.0, p-value = 0.683
```

Great, W-, as I expected; p-value is far bigger than 0.05, so great too.

In R:

```
sample = c(4, 5, 6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 8, 9, 4, 6, 7, 2, 5, 6)
med0 = 5

wilcox.test(sample, mu = med0, correct = FALSE, exact = FALSE)
```

And I get:

```
Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  sample
V = 85, p-value = 0.683
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 5
```

Same p-value but... 85? W+? Why? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read the help page for `wilcox.test.`  Focus on the "Note" section near the end.

Comment: This post may answer your question. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2625#issuecomment-20913083